# Python Re.Sub Function Usage Issue

Tags: python, regex, syntax, substitution

I need help with this `re.sub` function.
For example, if I wanted to replace "string" with "abc"
but I want `#include <string.h>` to remain the same so that the syntax does not get disturbed and all the other "string" variables get replaced with "abc". How can I write the `re.sub` function?

The Python code is:

```
result = re.sub("string","abc", test_str, 0)
```

`test_str` is this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Function(unsigned char *string, unsigned char *key)
{
unsigned int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < s(string); i++)
{
    
    string[i] = ~ string[i];
}

return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
result = re.sub(r"\bstring\b(?!\.h\b)", "abc", test_str)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Vw7lj1/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  string                   'string'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    h                        'h'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but if for example i use syntax like this
result = re.sub(regex[i],"abc", test_str, 0) here regex[i] is every time different as iterated in the loop. so how can i put ur solution in this situation?

Comment: @AbdulHannan `fr"\b{regex[i]}\b(?!\.h\b)"`